# c++14 unique_ptr and make unique_ptr error use of deleted function 'std::unique-ptr'

Tags: c++, pointers, c++14, unique-ptr

I have a function like this..

```
unique_ptr<Node> test(unique_ptr<Node> &&node, string key)
{
    if(!node)
    {
        return make_unique<Node>(key);
    }
    else
        return node;
}
```

I want to create a node if the node is null, or to return the node. but it errors out saying "use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr' ". What have I done wrong?

Comment: You can't copy a `unique_ptr`. That's what the error is trying to tell you. You'll notice it names the copy constructor, not just `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Thanks Chris..how should i fix it?

Comment: You might want to *move* `node` rather than copy it.

Comment: If the purpose is to forward `node` as the resulting pointer, then `return std::move(node);`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the way you are calling the function. But first of all you should accept your `std::unique_ptr` by value, not *r-reference*.

Then you need to `std::move()` your pointer when calling the function:

```
// accept by value
std::unique_ptr<Node> test(std::unique_ptr<Node> node)
{
    if(!node)
        return std::make_unique<Node>();

    return node;
}

int main()
{
    auto n = std::make_unique<Node>();

    n = test(std::move(n)); // move the pointer
}
```

A `std::unique_ptr` can't be copied otherwise it would not be unique. You hav to *move* them.